# RoR: Create parent through child

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and keep struggling with the following issue. Unfortunately, hours of search have not led to a solution, so I would be more than happy to get your input.

On creating an order, I attempt to create a client (as parent) and order items (as child). The latter works fine. However, on saving the order, both order and client are stored in the database with the exception that the *client_id* is not passed to the order record.

Here follows my code:

**Company Model**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :orders,     foreign_key: "client_id"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders

  validates :name, 
            :presence => true,
            :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false } 

  validates_associated  :users,
                        :orders

  attr_accessible :name, 
                  :account, 
                  :users_attributes,
                  :orders_attributes,  
                  :company_id
end
```

**Order Model**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :order_items
    accepts_nested_attributes_for   :order_items

    belongs_to  :client, class_name: "Company",
                                    foreign_key: "id"
    accepts_nested_attributes_for   :client

    attr_accessible :order_items_attributes,
                    :order_number,
                    :client_attributes,
                    :client_id

    validates_associated    :order_items

    validates_presence_of   :order_number
                            :client_id
end
```

**Orders Controller**

```
  def create
    @order = @client.orders.build(params:[orders])
    puts @order.to_yaml

    respond_to do |format|

      if @order.save!
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @order, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**New Order Form**

```
<%= simple_form_for @order, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => @order %> 
  <div class = "span3">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :client do |client_builder| %>
      <%= client_builder.input  :name, 
                                :label => 'Client' %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.input :order_number %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :order_items do |items_builder| %>
        <%= items_builder.input :reference_number %>
        <%= items_builder.input :item_description %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.button  :submit,
                  :class => 'btn'%>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                              orders_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for your help in advance!
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
belongs_to  :client, class_name: "Company", foreign_key: "id"
```

Should be

```
belongs_to  :client, class_name: "Company", foreign_key: "client_id"
```

Also i would update your migration and make that field not nullable, better to get an exception than saving an order without client